# How to make hr longer between cols?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap for my column structure and want to draw a horizontal line between the columns:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-2 icon">

        <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 height hidden-xs">
        <p>mycomp account number</p><span class="text">2000299999940</span>
      </div>
      <div class="visible-xs height">
        <hr>
        <p class="col-xs-5">mycomp account number:</p>
        <p class="col-xs-7">2000299999940</p>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1">
      <hr class="line" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.line {
    width: 200px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #dadada;
    margin-right:40px;
  }
```

Because of the bootstrap columnstructure there are margins involved, but how can I make the line without all the space ie make it wider? Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/RodJoE)

Comment: please explain little more..

Comment: I just want to make the line longer/wider

Comment: If I make the width higher it goes through the second column

Comment: remove the padding on the col??

Answer (score 0):

well in case you want to ignore the default padding and margin in bootstrap make a class in css file as

```
.no-padding-margin
{
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

and then apply this class to your bootstrap columns as

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 no-padding-margin">
      <div class="col-md-2 icon">

        <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 height hidden-xs">
        <p>mycomp account number</p><span class="text">2000299999940</span>
      </div>
      <div class="visible-xs height">
        <hr>
        <p class="col-xs-5">mycomp account number:</p>
        <p class="col-xs-7">2000299999940</p>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 no-padding-margin">
      <hr class="line" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a codepen for this because it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

well as i understand you just want your line to be longer .
so why don't you remove the paddings from the col the line is in. and also add `width:100%` on the `.line` if you want.

code :

```
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}
.col-md-1 {
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and updated the codepen but the line is still way short :(